# Multiplication of elements in list of lists

Tags: python

hello I am trying to multiply certain lists in a list of lists by variables.

let's say I have the following

```
[['', 'header1.txt', 'header2.txt', 'header3.txt', 'header4.txt'],
 ['cow', 4, 3, 2, 10],
 ['pig', 20, 4, 7, 2]]
```

and the following variables :

```
cows = 2
pigs = 4
```

How would I multiply the cow list by the variable cow and the pig list by the variable pig to create

```
[['', 'header1.txt', 'header2.txt', 'header3.txt', 'header4.txt'],
 ['cow', 8.0, 6.0, 4.0, 4.0],
 ['pig', 80.0, 16.0, 28.0, 8.0]]
```

It doesnt have to be floats, but this would be ideal.
I tried it with something like this

```
matrix = [['', 'header1.txt', 'header2.txt', 'header3.txt', 'header4.txt'],
          ['cow', 4, 3, 2, 10],
          ['pig', 20, 4, 7, 2]]
cows = 2
pigs = 4
weightmatrix = []

for value in matrix:
    try:
        weightmatrix.append(matrix[1]*cows)
        weightmatrix.append(matrix[2]*pigs)
    except:
        pass
print(weightmatrix)
```

However for me this creates double the elements in every list, it just seems to copy and paste the list behind each other instead of multiplying the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace each item individually in the list when you get a match. You can't just multiply the whole list.

I would also suggest putting the operations into  dict for convenience.

```
matrix = [
    ['', 'header1.txt', 'header2.txt', 'header3.txt', 'header4.txt'],
    ['cow', 4, 3, 2, 10],
    ['pig', 20, 4, 7, 2],
]
ops = {
    'cow': 2,
    'pig': 4,
}

for row in matrix:
    if row[0] in ops:
        for i in range(1, len(row)):
            row[i] *= ops[row[0]]
```

Comment: This works great, I have one more question:
How do I convert the results into floats?

Comment: @Kareltje12 you could do `row[i] *= float(ops[row[0]])`. Or make the map `ops = {'cow': 2.0,'pig': 4.0}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd solve it:

```
matrix = [['', 'header1.txt', 'header2.txt', 'header3.txt', 'header4.txt'],
          ['cow', 4, 3, 2, 10],
          ['pig', 20, 4, 7, 2]]
multipliers = {
    "cow": 2,
    "pig": 4,
}

for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    m = multipliers.get(row[0])
    if m is not None:
        matrix[i] = [row[0]] + [x * m for x in row[1:]]
```

Comment: Would using a generator expression potentially be better here? `[row[0], *(x * m for x in row[1:])]` Avoids the extra container, but not exactly sure if it would gain anything.

Comment: @flakes Maybe yours is a bit more efficient, don't know. Micro-optimization either way though.

Comment: Looks like we also came up with pretty much the same answer at the same time :P

Comment: @flakes Or a `map` maybe? `row[1:] = map(m.__mul__, row[1:])`

Comment: @KellyBundy Don't like that, sorry.

Comment: @KellyBundy huh, neat. Didn't realize you could assign a `map` instance to a slice!

Comment: @orlp What part(s)? The `map`, the `__mul__`, or the `row[1:] = `?

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't think the `map` + `.__mul__` is cleaner than a generator expression.

Comment: @orlp I see (I know, I appear to be the only one who doesn't dislike doing that :-). I think the `row[1:] = ` is really cleaner, though.